# Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters are deprecated

Tags: html, google-chrome, console, resources, newline

Does anyone know what this warning is referring to and how I would go about resolving it?

> [Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters are deprecated, and may be blocked in M60, around August 2017. Please remove newlines from places like element attribute values in order to continue loading those resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5735596811091968 for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found elsewhere, this is caused by having a new line character within an element attribute.

The newline character has to be removed or replaced using, for example:

```
String.replace(/\n|\r/g, "");
```