# Any one know how to solve this?

Tags: javascript

Am getting this warning in console while running javascript code. :

> "blocking resources whose URLs contain both \n and < characters".

Not able to run Javascript code.

Answer from anyone ll great help..

code is here:

```
let val;

let list = document.querySelector("ul.collection");

let listItem = document.querySelector("li.collection-item:first-child");

val = listItem;
val = list;

console.log(val);
```

Thank you,

Comment: What's JS code?

Comment: Please include your JavaScript code in the original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983981/resource-requests-whose-urls-contain-raw-newline-characters-are-deprecated) or [Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters are deprecated in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203638)

Answer (score -1):

You have to replace the newline character in string.

```
String.replace(/\n|\r/g, "");
```